# Laravel Model: how to get all relations as array with custom array keys?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables: countries and cities. Each of them contain columns: id, name, etc. I can get all countries with all their cities as an array:

```
$countries = Country::with('cities')->select('id', 'name')->get();
$countries->toArray();
```

Result:

```
[
  [
     id: 1
     name: Zimbabe
     cities: [[id: 1, name:'Capital City'], /*etc...*/]           
  ],
//etc.
]
```

But I need different array keys: 'key' and 'title' instead of 'id' and 'name', because of a required javascript component:

```
[
  [
     key: 1
     title: Zimbabe
     cities: [[key: 1, title:'Capital City'], /*etc...*/]           
  ],
//etc..
]
```

I think, I can do it via attribute accessors. But what to do, if in the future a new column is added to the table with, for example, a 'key' field? This violates the accessor's logic.

And a second problem: how do I get all model relations with custom array keys?

At this moment I think that the only solution is to manually create a new array via recursion after fetch model result with all relations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `toArray` method for `City` model to get city in valid format like this:

```
public function toArray()
{
   return [
      'key' = $this->id,
      'title' => $this->name,
   ];
}
```

or if you need more data here you can use:

```
public function toArray()
{
   $data = parent::toArray();
   $data['key'] = $data['id'];
   unset($data['id']);
   $data['title'] = $data['name'];
   unset($data['name']);
   return $data;
}
```

and it should do the trick. But obviously you cannot do anything with situation when key or title will be added to table and you would like to return also them because they will be overriden by id and name you assigned to those keys.

Comment: Yes, but if I do it, I lose opportunity to get data with original key names. May to crete self function toMyArray() for each model (with same code)? - but how to make them work together in the preparation of all relations?

Comment: @Stanislav As I said you cannot do anything with this. If you want to assign something to key and you want to keep original key it's obviously not possible

Comment: Yes, I understand. But maybe create  own model function, which will be called at the request of all relations? $model->getMyArrya() - its really for single model, but don't work when requested all relations. This could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it via attribute Accessors.

Not sure this answers your question in whole or in part, but its an approach to think about. Recently i've been using the Presenter Pattern.

[laracasts/Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter)

A presenter is just a class that bolts onto your model object with methods that transform and/or formats the data.

Comment: Good idea, but Presenter will not called at moment, when we get model with all its relations:  Country::with('cities')->get();

Comment: I am trying to understand why it has to be like that. I'm not sure I understand your requirement for that. You are going to have to transform your data at some point. Since it sounds like you are building an API Fractal might be worth a look http://fractal.thephpleague.com/ it handles embeded relationships as well.